# How is the spectral norm of a row matrix calculated?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, spectral-norm

If $x \in \mathbb{R}^{1\times n}$ is a row matrix, is it true that $\| x \|_2 = \| x^T \|_2 = \sqrt{x x^T}$?

Note that $\| x \|_2$ is the induced matrix norm and $\| x^T \|_2$ is the vector $2$-norm.

Comment: $\|x\|_2=\|x\|_2^T$ is easily shown, since $\|x\|_2$ is a $1\times 1$ matrix (also known as "a number"), and therefore necessarily symmetric.

Comment: I guess you want $\|x\|_2 = \|x^T\|_2$. Furthermore I guess that you want that $\|x\|_2$ should be a matrix norm and $\|x^T\|_2$ is the scalarproduct norm of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Anyway, you should clarify that.

Comment: Yes Arthur you are right. I edited my question.

Comment: Thanks Nathaneal I edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: See that when you multiply a row vector with a column vector it is a number in $\Bbb R$.

Comment: I can't see how this hint answers the question. Being $x$ the row vector the OP defined and $y$ a column vector, we have $|xy| = |x_1y_1 + \ldots + x_ny_n|$. Since the OP was denoting $\|x\|_2$ to be the induced matrix norm, we have $$\|x\|_2 = \sup_{\|y\|=1} |xy| = \sup_{\|y\|=1} |x_1y_1 + \ldots x_n y_n|.$$
On the other hand, the Euclidean norm of $x^T$ is $\|x^T\| = \sqrt{ |x_1|^2 + \ldots + |x_n|^2|}$. How exactly your hint clarifies the difference between $\sqrt{ |x_1|^2 + \ldots + |x_n|^2}$ and $ \sup_{\|y\|=1} |x_1y_1 + \ldots x_n y_n|$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's true. For clarity, let us denote the Euclidean norm of a row or column vector by $\|\cdot\|_E$. Pick any orthogonal matrix $V$ whose first column is $\frac{1}{\|x^T\|_E}x^T$. Then
$$
x=1\pmatrix{\|x^T\|_E&0&\ldots&0}V^T
$$
is a singular value decomposition of $x$ and it follows that the induced $2$-norm of $x$ is $\|x^T\|_E$.

Alternatively, since
$$
\|x\|_2
=\max_{\substack{\|v^T\|_E=1\\ v^T\in\mathbb R^{n\times1}}}\|xv^T\|_E
=\max_{\substack{\|v^T\|_E=1\\ v^T\in\mathbb R^{n\times1}}}\langle x^T,v^T\rangle
\le\max_{\substack{\|v^T\|_E=1\\ v^T\in\mathbb R^{n\times1}}}\|x^T\|_E\|v^T\|_E
=\|x^T\|_E
$$
and equality holds when $v$ is a unit vector pointing in the same direction of $x$, we conclude that $\|x\|_2=\|x^T\|_E$.